# Pandas : How to calculate PCT Change for all columns dynamically?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following pandas df by using the following command, how to get PCT Change for all the columns dynamically for AAL , AAN ... 100 more

```
price['AABA_PCT_CHG'] = price.AABA.pct_change()

         AABA        AAL        AAN  AABA_PCT_CHG
0   16.120001   9.635592  18.836105           NaN
1   16.400000   8.363149  23.105881      0.017370
2   16.680000   8.460282  24.892321      0.017073
3   17.700001   8.829385  28.275263      0.061151
4   16.549999   8.839100  27.705627     -0.064972
5   15.040000   8.654548  27.754738     -0.091239
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply on dataframe like

```
In [424]: price.pct_change().add_suffix('_PCT_CHG')
Out[424]:
   AABA_PCT_CHG  AAL_PCT_CHG  AAN_PCT_CHG
0           NaN          NaN          NaN
1      0.017370    -0.132057     0.226680
2      0.017073     0.011614     0.077315
3      0.061151     0.043628     0.135903
4     -0.064972     0.001100    -0.020146
5     -0.091239    -0.020879     0.001773

In [425]: price.join(price.pct_change().add_suffix('_PCT_CHG'))
Out[425]:
        AABA       AAL        AAN  AABA_PCT_CHG  AAL_PCT_CHG  AAN_PCT_CHG
0  16.120001  9.635592  18.836105           NaN          NaN          NaN
1  16.400000  8.363149  23.105881      0.017370    -0.132057     0.226680
2  16.680000  8.460282  24.892321      0.017073     0.011614     0.077315
3  17.700001  8.829385  28.275263      0.061151     0.043628     0.135903
4  16.549999  8.839100  27.705627     -0.064972     0.001100    -0.020146
5  15.040000  8.654548  27.754738     -0.091239    -0.020879     0.001773
```

Comment: This solves my purpose of pct_change, but how do I solve the following for all columns ?
    price['AABA_LOG_RETURN'] = np.log(price.AABA) - np.log(price.AABA.shift(1))

Comment: @Shakti One question per question thread please. If this solved the problem you had in the question, please mark it accepted and open a new one.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks - I figured it out from another post - price.apply(np.log).diff().add_suffix('_LOG_PCT_CHG')